# HTML fix position when minimize the window

Tags: html, css

I am new at HTML and want to know how to fix the position of my elements in a window because every time I try to minimize the window everything becomes messy. I am about to make a website and this is my first try so bear with errors. Here's my code:

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #cc9966;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.Container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-family: Lucida handwriting;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1rem 1rem 5rem black;
}

header .choice a {
  padding: .8rem;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: solid rgba(57, 38, 19);
  background: #f9f2ec;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=content-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title> WEBSITE OF LB21 </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="LB21.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="Container">

    <div class=title>

      <h2> LUSCIOUS BITES </h2>

    </div>

    <center>
      <p class="choice">
        <a href="#home">HOME</a>
        <a href="#speciality">SPECIALITY</a>
        <a href="#popular">POPULAR</a>
        <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
        <a href="#review">REVIEW</a>
        <a href="#order">ORDER</a>
      </p>
    </center>

    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">

      <div class="content">
        <h3>food made with love</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas accusamus tempore temporibus rem amet laudantium animi optio voluptatum. Natus obcaecati unde porro nostrum ipsam itaque impedit incidunt rem quisquam eos!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">order now</a>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="images/home-img.png" alt="">
      </div>

    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```

The image below shows the issues I'm having:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! There are several errors in your HTML that you should fix before we can help. You have a closing `</header>` tag, but no opening one. Also, this is minor, but please do not capitalize CSS classes - for instance `Container` should be `container`. That's more nit-picky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body,
html {
  background-color: #cc9966;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.Container {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  font-family: Lucida handwriting;
  font-size:calc(34px + 2.2vw);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1rem 1rem 5rem black;
}

header {
  padding: .8rem;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: solid rgba(57, 38, 19);
  background: #f9f2ec;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}.choice  {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly; 
  max-width: 900px 
}
.choice a {
  padding: .8rem;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: solid rgba(57, 38, 19);
  background: #f9f2ec;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=content-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <title> WEBSITE OF LB21 </title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="Container">

    <div class=title>

      <h2> LUSCIOUS BITES </h2>

    </div>

    <center>
      <p class="choice">
        <a href="#home">HOME</a>
        <a href="#speciality">SPECIALITY</a>
        <a href="#popular">POPULAR</a>
        <a href="#gallery">GALLERY</a>
        <a href="#review">REVIEW</a>
        <a href="#order">ORDER</a>
      </p>
    </center>

    

    <section class="home" id="home">

      <div class="content">
        <h3>food made with love</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas accusamus tempore temporibus rem amet laudantium animi optio voluptatum. Natus obcaecati unde porro nostrum ipsam itaque impedit incidunt rem quisquam eos!</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">order now</a>
      </div>

      <div class="image">
        <img src="images/home-img.png" alt="">
      </div>

    </section>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer but how about the title cause it is still compressed when the window is minimized

Comment: @TequilaLucille Do you mean you don't want the title wrapping?

Comment: yes, i just want it  change its size when the window has change its size also or being minimized

Comment: @TequilaLucille I've updated the code to give you a responsive title.